# One to one relationship, different key column name, Entity Framework, Code First approach

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have two tables that have already been created. `Document` and `DocumentStyle`. They have a one to one relationship through the `DocumentID` column. However, it is called `Id` in `Document` table, and `DocumentId` in `DocumentStyle` table.

Something like this

```
Document            DocumentStyle 
|----------|        |----------------|
|Id - Key  |<------>|DocumentId- key |
|Name-VChar|        |Color     -VChar|
|Desc-VChar|        |Font      VChar |
|----------|        |----------------|
```

I'm getting the following error in VS

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'DocumentStyle' on type
> 'KII.Models.Document' is not valid.
> The foreign key name 'DocumentId' was
> not found on the dependent type
> 'KII.Models.Document'. The Name value
> should be a comma separated list of
> foreign key property names.

This is part of the code for the Document model class

```cs
[ForeignKey("DocumentId")]  
public DocumentStyle DocumentStyle { get;set; }
```

EDIT:

This is the code of my classes.

```cs
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FundId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
        
    [ForeignKey("FundId")]
    public Fund Fund { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public DocumentStyle DocumentStyle { get; set; }
        
    public Document()
    {

    }

    public Document(DocumentStyle documentStyle)
    {
        DocumentStyle = documentStyle;
    }

}

public class DocumentStyle
{
    public DocumentStyle()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Document ID")]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")]
    public Document Document { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Foreground Color")]
    public string TitleForegroundColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Background Color")]
    public string TitleBackgroundColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Font Family")]
    public string TitleFontFamily { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Font Size")]
    public string TitleFontSize { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Font Style")]
    public string TitleFontStyle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Font Weight")]
    public string TitleFontWeight { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Title Text Decoration")]
    public string TitleTextDecoration { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Foreground Color")]
    public string SectionTitleForegroundColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Background Color")]
    public string SectionTitleBackgroundColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Font Family")]
    public string SectionTitleFontFamily { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Font Size")]
    public string SectionTitleFontSize { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Font Styled")]
    public string SectionTitleFontStyle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Font Weight")]
    public string SectionTitleFontWeight { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Section Title Text Decoration")]
    public string SectionTitleTextDecoration { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Foreground Color")]
    public string ParagraphForegroundColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Background Color")]
    public string ParagraphBackgroundColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Font Family")]
    public string ParagraphFontFamily { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Font Size")]
    public string ParagraphFontSize { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Font Style")]
    public string ParagraphFontStyle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Font Weight")]
    public string ParagraphFontWeight { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Paragraph Text Decoration")]
    public string ParagraphTextDecoration { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Logo")]
    public byte[] Logo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ForeignKey` attribute pairs foreign key property and navigation property. It doesn't define property from related table! So you must use either:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public DocumentStyle DocumentStyle { get; set; }
}
```

if `Document` is dependent entity or:

```
public class DocumentStyle
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")] // Should not be needed
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

if `DocumentStyle` is dependent

Comment: Great. I got it wrong. It did the trick. I passed that error. However, I get this one now. " Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Document_DocumentStyle_Source' in relationship 'Document_DocumentStyle'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be 1"

Comment: Show your entities or fluent mapping. This looks like you are trying to define one side optional when it is not possible.

Comment: ForeignKey attribute must be used only on one side of relation where foreign key is defined. I guess `Document` is principal in your model so remove the attribute from `DocumentStyle` property.

Comment: Great, You're the man! that did the trick. However, my reference to DocumentStyle in the Document instance is null.

Comment: You must explicitly load the relation or make navigation properties virtual.