# Entity Framework: Trying to query an entity with a foreign key relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group {
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    // other properties
}
```

Running this linq query:

```
myContext.Users.Where(u => u.SomeProperty = 4);
```

yields this sql query:

```
select
    extent1.Id as Id
    extent1.SomeProperty as SomeProperty
    extent1.Group_Id as Group_Id
from
    dbo.Users as extent1
```

It's weird that it decided not to camel case the association column like it did with the other properties. Is there some reason for this?

In any case, I added mapping code to try and fix it:

```
var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
entity.HasRequired( a => a.Group )
    .WithRequiredDependent()
    .Map( a => a.MapKey( "GroupId" ) );
```

Unfortunately, querying with linq produces this query:

```
select
    extent1.Id as Id
    extent1.SomeProperty as SomeProperty
    extent1.GroupId as GroupId
    extent1.Group_Id as Group_Id
from
    dbo.Users as extent1
```

It looks a bit better, but obviously doesn't work still because my table has the column GroupId and not Group_Id. Does anyone know what's going on here or how to fix it?

Comment: Look at this please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5995211/2524304

Comment: Is `User - Group` 1:1? It sounds like n-1.

Comment: A group has many users. A user can belong to only one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the mapping `User-Group` is n - 1 the mapping should be:

```
var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
entity.HasRequired(a => a.Group)          // user has one Group
      .WithMany()                         // Group has many Users
      .Map( a => a.MapKey("GroupId"));
```

EF created the `Group_Id` column itself for the 1-n association it inferred from your class model, while `GroupId` was added because of the 1:1 association you mapped yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write it as follow

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int SomeProperty {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("Group")] 
   public int GroupId {get;set;}
   public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Group_Id cloumn is created automatically when not define foreignKey property.